# how to record video rendered on a UIview

Tags: swift, twilio

I am using the twilio tviVideoview, to render the video being played on a UIView element in xcode. Since we are unsure of the format of the video, I would like to record the video rendered on the view, and store it. How do i do that in xcode(using swift)?
 In android it is possible by taking snapshots of the ui view itself...but not sure about xcode.

Comment: found any thing?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can't find, after a search, an easy way to record both the video and sound from a video in a UIView. However, there is a library called [Glimpse](https://github.com/wess/Glimpse) that allows you to record the video playing in a UIView that you might want to check out.

Comment: Thanks Phil, but as I mentioned in the question, I need a swift/based library, glimpse seems to be objective-C based

Comment: Oh, can't you just use the Obj-C lib within Swift?

Comment: not acceptable for my project, btw do you have a solution for recording the audio being streamed using twilio? does the api allow a way to record the audio being streamed?

Comment: There is nothing out of the box for recording the audio on the device in the SDK. However, in private beta right now we are testing a media server that can do the recording of the video and audio.

Comment: ah,I see but since its still private beta, I don't believe we have access to it. Any suggestions from someone, to record the TVIAudioTrack, which is being streamed by each participant in the TVIRoom, and save it to disk?

Comment: I don't think there is access to the underlying stream to record from (someone was asking previously about doing speech recognition on the stream with `SFSpeechRecognizer` but the result is that it's not available yet). This may be something that appears later in the SDK, but I can't promise anything for now I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd probably recommend having Twilio do the recording of video, by [creating a group room and enabling `recordParticipantsOnConnect`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#example-3-create-a-group-room-enable-recording-and-set-a-status-callback-url). That saves the device from doing an intensive action and means you can get the videos in a consistent format.